# How can I exclude external .jar from obfuscation by Proguard (Android project)?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

When I export android project with proguard.cfg, all referenced .jar files are obfuscated as well. How can I exclude some of that .jars from obfuscation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't want to edit the Ant script, you can add -keep options to proguard.cfg for the classes in those external jars. For instance:

```
-keep class othercode.** { *; }
```

Or with a regular expression containing a negator:

```
-keep class !mycode.** { *; }
```

The standard Ant script will still merge all referenced jars in the single output jar though.

Comment: I also did it this way (but used keepclasseswithmembers class and keep interface) It worked more or less fine in my case, since separate .jar files had different package names...

Comment: Also thought it keeps the names, the code is still seems to be processed and obfuscated.

Comment: @Eric please reply, in android studio where to add these lines, either in 'proguard-project.txt' or 'proguard-rules.pro' ?

Comment: @ShirishHerwade proguard-rules.pro

Comment: FYI: The second syntax (negator syntax) won't work in R8 (which is what runs obfuscation in newer versions of the Android build tools), you need to add an extra ",**", see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59273778

Answer (score 5):

In your config file, set up your jars as library jars instead of input jars.  This leaves them untouched.

```
-libjars <path/to/jars>
```

Comment: I don't setup input or library jars. This is done by platform ant script. And editing that file is what I try to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Using proguard maven plugin I do it like that

```
<inclusion>
   <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
   <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
   <library>true</library>
   <filter>!META-INF/**</filter>
</inclusion>
```

The

```
<library>true</library>
```

lead to the external jar merged into the final jar after the obfuscation. But this might lead to the Manifest being overwritten. I haven't figured out yet how to avoid that the best way.