# how can I do no proguard to a jar in android

Tags: android, proguard, kindle-fire

I include a jar to my project.  I put the jar in libs folder. Then I add to build path. I run the project on my device, it runs fine. But when I signed it, it runs crash. I guess it was the `proguard`.

If I don't wannna progurad the very jar, How can I write the `proguard-project.txt`?

the jar is amazon mobile ad jar. https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/mobileads.html

========edit=============

```
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.vtube.app.VideoGridviewAdapter.createViewFromResource(Unknown Source)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.vtube.app.VideoGridviewAdapter.getView(Unknown Source)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.vtube.component.ListToGridAdapter.bindView(Unknown Source)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.vtube.component.ListToGridAdapter.bindGridView(Unknown Source)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.vtube.component.ListToGridAdapter.getView(Unknown Source)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2043)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1330)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1603)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1873)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11307)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11307)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11307)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11307)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11307)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11307)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11307)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1501)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2462)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4560)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    ... 50 more
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=390; index=-6
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:120)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-26 23:13:07.973: E/AndroidRuntime(25405):    ... 53 more
```

this FC only happen when it's signed. So I guess it's the proguard problem. `cause by` part is in the `amazon ad jar`.

I put a lot of `keep` in `proguard-project.txt` :

```
-dontoptimize

-keep class com.amazon.device.ads.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers class com.amazon.** {*;}
-keepclassmembernames class com.amazon.** {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
 }
```

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475074/how-can-i-exclude-external-jar-from-obfuscation-by-proguard-android-project

Comment: @Vamshi see my edit, I add some log info

Comment: @birdy your link cannot solve my problem, thank you any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize proguard running. I dont know well, but I remember like this.

Some Samples:
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

Example:

```
-injars       myapplication.jar
-outjars      myapplication_out.jar
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-printmapping myapplication.map

-keep public class mypackage.MyMain {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the `injar` and `outjar` 'libraryjars` means... I put my `proguard-project.txt` in my edit. where am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can try this. I copied from project.properties


# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:/android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt