# Exporting of apk file failed if I enabled ProGuard

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter, proguard

When I tried to export my apk file with ProGuard applied, eclipse returned a error message:

> Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

In the console I find this vast data (see below). I think this is because of twitter4j library. How do I resolve this error? Somewhere I heard that we can instruct ProGuard to ignore some libraries while obfuscating, how to ignore twitter in that way?

```
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Note: there were 1 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find superclass or interface javax.management.DynamicMBean
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.HttpHost: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.HttpVersion: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AUTH: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthOption: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeRegistry: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthState: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.BasicUserPrincipal: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.InvalidCredentialsException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.NTUserPrincipal: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.params.AuthParams: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.RedirectException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.params.AuthPolicy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.params.ClientParamBean: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParams: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContextConfigurer: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAcceptEncoding: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestClientConnControl: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestDefaultHeaders: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseAuthCache: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseContentEncoding: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.utils.CloneUtils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.utils.JdkIdn: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.utils.Punycode: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.utils.Rfc3492Idn: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.BasicEofSensorWatcher: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.MultihomePlainSocketFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParamBean: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnPerRouteBean: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRouteParamBean: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRouteParams: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.routing.BasicRouteDirector: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.routing.RouteTracker: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.ssl.StrictHostnameVerifier: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.util.InetAddressUtils: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.cookie.CookieIdentityComparator: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.cookie.CookieOrigin: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.cookie.CookiePathComparator: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.cookie.CookieRestrictionViolationException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpecRegistry: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.cookie.params.CookieSpecParamBean: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.ContentType: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.SerializableEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpServerConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpClientConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpResponseFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpServerConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.EnglishReasonPhraseCatalog: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.HttpConnectionMetricsImpl: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.NoConnectionReuseStrategy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpServerConnection: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.AuthSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicSchemeFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestSchemeFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosSchemeFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMScheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMSchemeFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.RFC2617Scheme: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoSchemeFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.UnsupportedDigestAlgorithmException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractAuthenticationHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy
[2013-12-18 20:18:19 - Quilters] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient: can't find referenced class org.ap....etc too large
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721397/how-to-make-proguard-ignore-external-libraries

Comment: May also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475074/how-can-i-exclude-external-jar-from-obfuscation-by-proguard-android-project

Comment: I just ran into this last week. Please see my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481752/gradle-failed-to-build-when-proguard-is-activated/20339590#20339590